# How to get the Windows 7 theme name

Tags: c#, winapi

Windows 7 comes with several built-in themes. They can be accessed by right-clicking the desktop and choosing Personalize.  Under Personalize, there is a section names "Aero Themes" containing themes like "Architecture" "Nature" and so on.

I tried using uxtheme.dll's GetCurrentThemeName, but it's actually giving the style name:
"C:\Windows\resources\Themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles" unless my current theme is set to Windows Basic, in which case it returns an empty string.  Is there an API that actually returns the theme name, like "Nature" "Architecture" etc...?

The code I tried is as follows:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
public extern static Int32 GetCurrentThemeName(StringBuilder stringThemeName, 
    int lengthThemeName, StringBuilder stringColorName, int lengthColorName, 
    StringBuilder stringSizeName, int lengthSizeName);

    StringBuilder stringThemeName = new StringBuilder(260);
    StringBuilder stringColorName = new StringBuilder(260);
    StringBuilder stringSizeName = new StringBuilder(260);

    Int32 s = GetCurrentThemeName(stringThemeName, 260,stringColorName, 260,stringSizeName, 260);
```

Comment: I found a registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes which contains an entry: "CurrentTheme" that gets populated with the theme file name, not the theme visual styles like the missnamed API mentioned in my original post.  For example, for the Nature Theme, it gets the value: "C:\Windows\resources\Themes\nature.theme" which is really good enough for me to parse it and get the name.  Of course there would be a problem if the theme's file name doesn't match the actual theme display name in the UI, but I will never hit that case in my limited scenario.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to lurk around the registry since it's more of an implementation detail than anything else. As [Brian Dishaw has mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631796/how-to-get-the-windows-7-theme-name/6632887#6632887), [`GetThemeDocumentationProperty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773402.aspx) seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the MSDN documentation it looks like [GetThemeDocumentationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773402(v=VS.85).aspx) might be what you are looking for.

You'll want to use it in conjunction with the theme file (which you alreayd have found in the registry) as well as by passing in the SZ_THDOCPROP_DISPLAYNAME as the second parameter of the method.

In addition here is a site that has the c# method wrapper for the p/invoke call: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/VisualStyles/UXTheme.cs.htm

Hope that helps.